# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled - seems like babel-config.json is being ignored

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, react-native-web

Error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

This is what my babel.config.json looks like though - I already have @babel/preset-react.. it seems like this file is just getting ignored.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
};
```

Context: Have a running react native app and trying to be able to use it on the web. I followed a tutorial and when I run react native web ("react-scripts start"), this is one of the errors I see.

Comment: Any resolution for this?